# How to create a private network with same production IP address? And How to make communication between using Linux machine as router?

Tags: linux, networking, router, vmware, iptables

I have production network in some IP address series say 192.168.X.X in VMware. In this I have some machine. I need to create a test setup. I have created a separate VLAN. Those VLAN were not connected to any physical adapter. I call it as "ISOLATED ENV". I have created the same machines as prod in "ISOLATED ENV".

```
Physical_adpter----VLAN X ----> PROD_MACHINE          ISOLATED_ENV---->TEST_PROD_MACHI
```

I have gave same IP address series in the production network to ISOLATED_ENV. So ISOLATED_ENV machine IP addresses are same as production IP address like 192.168.X.X.

Now I need to make a communication in between these network. I used a Linux machine with 2 NICs as a router for this purpose.

But the issue, the communication will takes  place either from one side. If I enabled the NIC2 and gave the production network gateway is the IP address in NIC2, the communication from Linux machine to ISOLATED_ENV will works. But  I cant ping from prod network to Linux machine (Router).

How can I achieve this? I configured IP forwarding some other IP rules in the Linux machine.

If I configured this with 2 different networks means it will work. If I am giving the same IP address as prod it won't.

Comment: If you have two networks that have the same IP addresses there is no way to distinguish it. You might find a way by setting up 1:1 static routes but this doesn't make sense. As you said your `ISOLATED_ENV` should be that: Isolated from your production network. If you want to let them communicate use different IPs.

Comment: Ya if am using same IPs means its working, but my requirements is have to use same ip in the ISOLATED_ENV. i have also read about the MASQUERADE technique. But i dont know how to configure with my requirements. 
From PROD to Some ip Series ...In linux machine i have the rules to redirect to machine in ISOLATED_ENV. lik this i have designed...But i cant make it works.

Comment: WHY are you even trying to let them communicate? Masquerade would setup a NAT. So you'd have to communicate with whatever gateway you have setup the NAT on in order to reach the services. E.g. you would map 192.168.14.14 to one your Isolated Environment IPs. What's your actual goal here?

Comment: My goal is to create a test environment same as production network with same IP in isolated network. And also need a communication with prod to isolated using that linux machine.

Comment: So to visualize this. `Your PC <== VLAN X, Prod Network ==> Linux <== Isolated Network ==> Test Machine`. Your Linux Machine has two NICs, one is part of the prod network and one is part of the isolated network. Right? The Network on each is is literally the same. What kind of communication are your trying to establish?

Comment: ya exactly.. but the isolated env is isolated from outside network (PROD). basically it wont communicate with prod and vice versa..So i need to establish a communication from production to isolated environment

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the same IP address on two different machines (one 192.168.1.1 on vlan x, and another 192.168.1.1 on the other network)? Or do you mean that you want to put one machine in another vlan but to use an address from the same subnet? i.e. all devices with addresses in 192.168.1.0/24, but one of them in another vlan? (By the other network, I mean your "isolated" network, which really isn't isolated if you're planning on routing to it)

Comment: thanks for u feedback... `one 192.168.1.1 on vlan x, and another 192.168.1.1 on the other network)?` this what i want.. in Which i need to communicate with these network using linux machine as router.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late to the party, but if the address which you are trying to ping from is in the same subnet as the isolated network then your router is going to send the response to the isolated network, hence, no reply.

1. You need to have a different client subnet to your isolated network.
2. You will only ever access one environment at a time.
3. Do not use a router unless using dynamic routes.  Better to use a RAS and establish an adhoc VPN tunnel to connect in to the isolated network.  This will cut the client off from the production network. When you disconnect, you are back on prod.
4. The binding order or route metric for the RAS must give precedence to the isolated network if there is any overlap between the RAS external subnet and the production subnet.

With all this in mind, it's likely there is a better solution as a whole to your problem.